# Result of FOR-loop if there is no related item

Tags: javascript, for-loop, podio

in a Podio calculation_field A I sum up the numbers of each related item (from another app) which contain "searchstring_1" in a text_field, in calculation_field B all related items which contain "searchstring_2"

No problem with the following code - IF there exists a related item. But if there exists no related item the "1" (= "nothing found"?) is displayed as "result". I tried several things, but can't find a solution for a calculation like: IF there is no related item then result = 0 (or "" or null), else let run the for-loop. Has anybody a tip what I can do? 
Thanks,
Rainer

```
var str = all of text_field;
var num = all of number_fields;
var total = 0;     

for(var i = 0; i < num.length ; i++) {
if (str[i].indexOf("searchstring_1") === 0) {
total += num[i];
}
}
```

Comment: *"But if there exists no related item the "1" (= "nothing found"?) is displayed as "result"."* What result? Displayed where? `total` will certainly be `0` if none of the strings starts with your search string.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation field always returns the last used value if you don't explicitly specify the return value. Maybe in your case the last value of `i`, `str[i].indexOf("searchstring_1")` would return -1, I think...

To make sure that the value of `total`is returned, simply add

```
total;
```

at the end of your calculation field value.

Enjoy,
Michael / Hamburg